# ResolvePackageNotFound when trying to create conda environment

Tags: python, python-bob

I am trying to reproduce the experiments in the paper Cross Modal Focal Loss for RGBD Face Anti-Spoofing (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.00948.pdf) . I have downloaded the source codes from gitlab and moved it to my linux (ubuntu) remote server . I am following the installation steps as given in the gitlab repo . The link to the gitlab repo is as follows :https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021

I am getting an error (ResolvePackageNotFound) when I try to build the environment as mentioned on step 2 . The python version in this environment is 3.7.5. Below is a screenshot of the code and error .
[Image of ResolvePackageNotFound Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmITP.png)
When i run conda list , those packages are all displayed as installed in the environment . Below is a screenshot .
[Image of conda list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqmYO.png)

I hope anyone would be able to assist me in solving this issue .

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the spec-file can you follow and let me know if it works with :

```
$ conda create --name bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021 --file spec-file.txt
```

Regards,
Anjith

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer . I have tried your suggestion and received CondaHTTPError for the packages that were unable to be downloaded . This is the error statement for one particular package:
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url <https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/conda/label/beta/linux-64/bob.extension-6.0.1b0-py37hedad887_83.conda>
Elapsed: 00:00.812679

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.